# JavaFX doesn't import properly

Tags: javafx

So I'm using IntelliJ 15.0 and Java JDK 8.0_31 and tried to write some JavaFX programs. The thing that is bugging me, is that there are some things that just simply won't really work out well.
I was trying out some different layouts, so I imported them like this: `import javafx.scene.layout.*` and I can use

```
StackPane stack = new StackPane();
```

without any problems, but whenever I try to use

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
```

it doesn't work. The code completion suggests that I write

```
java.scene.layout.Gridpane grid = new java.scene.layout.Gridpane();
```

Actually the program *does* work after writing it this way, but that really isn't the most pleasing thing to write everytime I want to create a GridPane and I don't see why the short form doesn't work. I can include all the other elements of JavaFX (I've used so far) in the short form without any problems and haven't had this problem before.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there another class named `GridPane`? Also I doubt that code works, since javafx packages start with `javafx.` and not with `java.` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/)

Comment: @fabian Ah sorry I wrote that wrong here, but in my javafile it is `import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;`. I don't think there is another class `GridPane`. If there was, how would I find out?

Comment: Most IDEs offer you to take you to the class definition. I don't know about IntelliJ, but in NetBeans you could just declare a `GridPane` (without `java.scene.layout.`) and let the IDE take you to the declaration of the type (navigate -> go to source). I guess InteliJ offers a similar feature.

Comment: @fabian Wow I feel dumb. I named the javafile GridPane.java and the main class `GridPane` because I just wanted to test GridPane out. I changed the name and it worked perfectly. That thing about looking at the class definitons really helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks likeyou have multiple Gridpane classes on your classpath, which makes this explicit naming necessary.

This has nothing to do specifically with JavaFX.